# How can I change when a week begins in Google Fit?

Tags: google-fit

I have set a weekly running goal in Google Fit.  However, a "week" means *Monday-Sunday*, but where I live the week is *Sunday-Saturday*.

Is there any way to change the definition of a week to match the local definitions?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @RayB: no, I stopped using Google Fit for unrelated reasons

Answer (score -1):

Fit uses the global operating system settings, it's a `locale` setting inherited from the language/region.

You can change the device language/region, under:

`Settings -> Language & Input -> Language (country/region)`

e.g. from English (US) to your correct region, such as English (UK) or other.